# Show list of unread books

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a Book model, a User model and a Read model. A Book can have many Reads and a User can have many Reads. Basically, in Read are all the books a certain User has read.

Now I want to show a list of all unread books of a certain user. Assuming the User is logged in and there is a current_user object, how would I get such a list?

I have this currently:

```
@unread_books = Book.find(:all, include: :reads, conditions: ["books.id NOT IN (?)", current_user.read_ids])
```

But this maps book id's to read id's. It should be something like:

```
conditions: ["books.id NOT IN (?)", current_user.read_book_ids]
```

But this gives an error:

```
undefined method `read_book_ids' for #<User:0x007fb21782b3f8>
```

So, how can I map book id's to the foreign key book id's in Read?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [LEFT OUTER JOIN](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html) to get these books; the books that has or has no reads for the current user id. Then select only those books with no attached user, which are included in an outer join (but not in an inner join). These are exactly the books that haven't been read by the current user:

```
SELECT books.id, books.title FROM books
LEFT OUTER JOIN readings 
  ON readings.book_id = books.id 
  AND readings.user_id = 1
WHERE readings.user_id IS NULL
```

[Tests on SQLFiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f2bb25/2)

In Rails, this might be something like this (not tested):

```
Books.joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN reads\
  ON reads.book_id = books.id\
  AND reads.user_id = :user_id", user_id: current_user.id)
.where("reads.user_id IS NULL")
```

The problem with your approach, is that you might be passing around a very large array of ids to ignore. This has to be searched for the id of each entry, which is pretty inefficient.